# Can't answer my own (old, protected) question

Tags: bug, privileges, protected-questions

I'm logged in to Physics.SE, I have 73 rep, and yet I noticed I can't answer [my own question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199721/how-do-suction-cups-work):

[image]

Supposedly the reputation requirement is only 10, yet I'm prevented from posting:

[image]

Since I hardly use this account, here's the entire `/reputation`:

```
total votes: 6
-- bonuses   (100)
-- 2011-08-18 rep +100  = 101       
 8    128510 (-50)
-- 2014-08-19 rep -50   = 51        
 16   200654 (2)
-- 2015-08-16 rep +2    = 53        
-- 2016-07-18 rep 0     = 53        
 2    199721 (10)
-- 2017-03-16 rep +10   = 63        
 2    199721 (10)
-- 2017-06-03 rep +10   = 73        
-- 2020-06-11 rep 0     = 73        

** rep today: 0
** rep this week (2020-09-20 - 2020-09-26): 0
** rep this month (2020-09-01 - 2020-09-30): 0
** rep this quarter (2020-07-01 - 2020-09-30): 0
** rep this year (2020-01-01 - 2020-12-31): 0
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 73 :)

days represented 7
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days
earned 2 reputation from suggested edits
```

Comment: This is already requested: [Allow OP to self-answer on their protected question without reputation restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253573/allow-op-to-self-answer-on-their-protected-question-without-reputation-restricti)

Comment: Thanks. I think I wouldn't have been surprised if my rep were less than 10. The confusing part is the calculation of **earned** reputation, and the "highly active question" message doesn't do much to explain this detail.

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231498/stack-exchange-doesnt-allow-me-to-answer-protected-questions-because-i-gave-awa